# How to get Android Studio main SourceSet with Gradle API?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm working on developing a gradle plugin for Android Studio.Here is my problem **How can I get Android Studio main SourceSet with Gradle API?**

I want to do some copy stuff with java source directory.
Before asking this question, I found something useful but not work.

```
SourceSet main = project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class).getSourceSets().getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME)
```

I get this error message
`Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SourceSet with name 'main' not found.`

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,the code doesn't work because it's only for the java project with java gradle plugin. So I googled and found something work around.
Here is my code.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    ...
    def sets;
    if (Utils.is140orAbove()) {
        sets = project.android.sourceSets;
    } else {
        sets = project.android.sourceSetsContainer;
    }
    sets.all { AndroidSourceSet sourceSet ->
        if(sourceSet.name.startsWith("main"))
            for(File file:sourceSet.java.getSrcDirs())
                if(file.exists()) {
                    mainSource = file;
                    break;
                }
    }
    ...
}
```

My code is not beautiful.Waiting for better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
android.sourceSets.main.java.getSrcDirs()[0].path
```

This works for me in Android Studio 3.1 and later

Answer (score 0):

```
project.android.sourceSets.main
```

works. Note that it has type [`AndroidSourceSet`](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html), not `SourceSet`. It has basically the same API, though, with Android-relevant additions.