# Running the main function of a program

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run a simple program via Android Studio and I get the following error (below).
I read about changing some things related to SDK and gradle, but I couldn't figure out was exactly my problem and couldn't fix it. Can someone say what is actually the problem and how should I sovle this?
The error is:

```
Executing tasks: [MainC.main()] in project 
C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\SomeProject


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\MainC_main__.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:MainC.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 0s
12:31:58: Task execution finished 'MainC.main()'.



The code:

package com.example.someproject;

public class MainC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want run java code in android studio without activity. Before that you need to tweak gradle with SourceSet.

Comment: ok. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37180829/7639056 take a look at this.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The build.gradle file that the guy in this post shows there is not very similar to the one I have on my Android Studio.
Should I copy the content of what he wrote there to my build.gradle file? Or maybe erase everything on mine and write what he wrote there?
Sorry for not understanding, this is kind of new to me.

Comment: Put that code at the end of your project level gradle build file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio refuses to run main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734823/android-studio-refuses-to-run-main)

Answer (score 12):

This one solved my issue - in Android Studio, the first time you run main() method, right click on the any part of the main() method, and select "Run 'YourClass.main()' with Coverage". Next time you run main(), you should be able to do it with by just clicking the run button.

I'm also a Java newbie, so I'm not sure why this works, but since it worked for me, it might be worth trying out.